# Special item to represent null values for ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, combobox

I'm implementing a user control in WPF using MVVM pattern. I want the control to contain an `ItemsControl`, specially a `ComboBox`, that contains a list of People. I want the first menu item to be labelled 'No Person' and  bind to `null` on the data source, while the remaining items are names of people that bind to `Person` objects.

The code for `Person` and the view model is as follows:

```
namespace NoValueItem
{
    public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public static bool Equals(Person a, Person b)
        {
            if (a == null)
                return b == null;
            return a.Equals(b);
        }

        public bool Equals(Person other)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
                return true;
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
                return false;
            return this.Name.Equals(other.Name);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return Equals(obj as Person);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Name.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public ObservableCollection<Person> ListOfPersons { get; } =
            new ObservableCollection<Person> {
                null,
                new Person() { Id = 1, Name = "Alice" },
                new Person() { Id = 2, Name = "Bob" },
                new Person() { Id = 3, Name = "Charlie" }
            };


        private Person _SelectedPerson;

        public Person SelectedPerson
        {
            get
            {
                return _SelectedPerson;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!Person.Equals(value, _SelectedPerson)) {
                    _SelectedPerson = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class NullSubstituteConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value ?? parameter;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (parameter == null)
                return value;
            return parameter.Equals(value) ? null : value;
        }
    }
}
```

And the view:

```
<Window x:Class="NoValueItem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NoValueItem"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ViewModel}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:ViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfPersons}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

At run-time, I get 4 items as I would expect: 1 blank menu item followed by 3 non-blank menu items, one for each `Person` in the `ViewModel.ListOfPersons` collection, with the item text bound to the `Name` property of the `Person`.

[image: Image showing MainWindow view at run-time]

I would like the first blank item to instead show the text 'No Person'. How can I do this?

One thing I've tried is using the following data converter, that converts a `null` reference to the object specified in the converter parameter:

```
namespace NoValueItem
{

    public class NullSubstituteConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value ?? parameter;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (parameter == null)
                return value;
            return parameter.Equals(value) ? null : value;
        }
    }
}
```

I then made the following changes to the view:

1. Added the `NullSubstituteConverter` from above as a static resource.
2. Added `Person` object as a static resources to represent the 'No Person' item and gave it the key 'NullPerson'.
3. Set the `NullSubstituteConverter` resource as the Converter for the binding for the `SelectedItem` property of the ComboBox.
4. Set the `NullSubstituteConverter` resource as the Converter for items in the data template for the ComboBox, so that the `null` item in the items source is converted to an the `NullPerson` object.

Here's the updated view:

```
<Window x:Class="NoValueItem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NoValueItem"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ViewModel}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:Person x:Key="NullPerson">
                <local:Person.Id>0</local:Person.Id>
                <local:Person.Name>No Person</local:Person.Name>
            </local:Person>
            <local:NullSubstituteConverter x:Key="NullSubstituteConverter"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:ViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfPersons}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson,
                  Converter={StaticResource NullSubstituteConverter},
                  ConverterParameter={StaticResource NullPerson}}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NullSubstituteConverter},
                           ConverterParameter={StaticResource NullPerson}}"
                           Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is closer to what I want. The blank menu item is now showing 'No Person', but there are still 2 problems:

1. When the view is first loaded, the 'No Person' item isn't automatically selected by default.
2. It's not possible to select the 'No Person' item.

[image: Image showing MainWindow view at run-time after add data converter]

I welcome any suggestions on how I can get the 'No Person' menu item working. It can be based on my approach above, or completely different approach as long as it works!

Comment: maybe, add `NoPerson` item (with id = 0) into `ListOfPersons` instead of `null`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Combobox DefaultValue (Please Select)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130763/wpf-combobox-defaultvalue-please-select)