# How do I display the first item in my ComboBox based on my dataBinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-5

Xaml:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1"
                  Name="CmbClasse"
                  Grid.Column="3"
                  Margin="5,5,5,5"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Classeses}"
                  SelectedValuePath="ClasseId"
                  DisplayMemberPath="ClasseName"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.CurrentSelectedPersonagem.IdClasse, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

When I open my application, the ComboBox do not have display any default item. But the item list is working, have all the items on it. Please help, if a image is needed just ask.
Thanks.

Comment: check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791184/setting-a-default-selected-item-in-combobox-in-wpf-mvvm-application

Comment: and this as well:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639533/default-value-for-combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method I use all the time.

Firstly, your View Model should have two properties, one to represent the collection, and the other to represent the selected item.

```
public IEnumerable<YourObject> MyObjects { get; private set; }
public YourObject SelectedObject { get; private set; }
```

*Note: It would be a good idea to use an `ObservableCollection` for `MyObjects`, and also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Use this **only** if you need to create brand new instances of your collection in the View Model.*

Your `ComboBox` should then bind to these properties, like so:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjects}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject}"
          ... 
          />
```

Now, here comes the magic. When you **create** your collection, simply set the `SelectedObject` to be the `FirstOrDefault` item in the list.

```
private void LoadData()
{
    //TODO: Load the data into the collection

    //Set the first item
    this.SelectedObject = MyObjects.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This will ensure that the first item is always selected. You **do not** need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `SelectedObject` property unless you are planning on manually changing the value of this property in your View Model.